Is gradient the direction of steepest change always?
Let's say I have a function $f(x_1, x_2, x_3,...,x_n)$ then gradient is defined as
$$ \left( \nabla f \right)  \left( \overrightarrow x \right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} +...+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}$$
Gradient is said to be the direction of steepest change where $\nabla f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.
If $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ vector components are not orthogonal to each other then is gradient still the direction of steepest change?
I infer that gradient is the direction of steepest change simply because it is defined as sum of terms resulting from differentiating the function partially with the vector components that are orthogonal to each other in $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector space because essentially you capture change along direction of all components without overlap in this gradient function which then makes it "friendly" for dot product with any vector in the $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector space.

What is your definition for "orthogonal components"?

No, when $\nabla f=0$ the gradient gives no direction, but there may still be a direction of steepest change. The gradient only gives it when the linear approximation of $f$ determines it.

my definition of orthogonal is like unit vector i hat and j hat in cartesian plane. the components with 0 projection on each other.

@conifold can you give an example for this case

$f(x,y)=x^2+4y^2$, the graph is elliptic paraboloid. $\nabla f(0,0)=0$, the direction of steepest change at $(0,0)$ is along the minor axis of the cross-sectional ellipses.

I think the confusion lies in the notation for functions. To answer your question: yes the gradient does indicate the direction of fastest increase locally (near the point where you calculate the gradient). Mabye it would be useful to see why the gradient is the steepest increase.
If we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ then we define the gradient as:
\begin{align}
\nabla f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right)^T
\end{align}
where I want to emphasize that $(x_1,...x_n)$ is just an arbitrary input from the domain of $f$.
To see why the gradient indicates the direction of steepest increase, we need the concept of a directional derivative (intuitively: the directional derivative $D_\mathbf{a}f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ says: look at the graph of $f$, and look into the direction $\mathbf{a}$, then the directional derivative is the rate of change in the direction $\mathbf{a}$.
You can prove that :
\begin{align}
D_\mathbf{a} f(x_1,\dots,x_n) =  \mathbf{a}\cdot \nabla f(x_1,\dots,x_n) 
\end{align}
and then applying the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to the equation above shows that:
$$
|D_\mathbf{a}f(x_1,\dots,x_n) | \leq |\mathbf{a}| | \nabla f(x_1,\dots,x_n)|
$$
with equality only when $\mathbf{a}$ is a scalar multiple of $\nabla f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Since the inequality is valid for every $\mathbf{a}$, we see that the only time it is equal to the upper bound, is when $\mathbf{a}$ is in the direction of the gradient, thus the gradient is the steepest increase.
Notice that we didnt mention anything about the orthogonality of $x_1,\dots,x_n$.
The gradient being the fastest increase is thus independent of the orthogonality of $x_1,\dots,x_n$.
Edit: Note that in some cases (e.g. when there is a maximum), there is no direction of steepest increase (because the function doesn't increase in any direction).

but if the vector basis (x1, x2,...,xn) for partial differentiation of the function to define gradient was not orthogonal w.r.t to each other then the gradient would only exist in a subspace instead of full R^n space? thus isn't orthogonality inherent in definition

If the situation were linear there would be an affine co-ordinte change into an orthogonal one. Perhaps this could be applied here./In 2-d for example, an affine map can make two vectors perpendicular by subtracting a multiple of the complement of one of them from the other.

sorry i don't follow (i am not strong at math).

In 2-d for example, an affine map can make two vectors perpendicular by subtracting a multiple of the complement of one of them from the other.
